# Why can't I refer to DATA in class context?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby it's really handy to store static text after `__END__` for arbitrary use via the `DATA` IO object:

```ruby
puts DATA.read # Prints "This is the stuff!"
__END__
This is the stuff!
```

However, when I try to reference the DATA object from the context of a new class I get unexpected errors (in Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0, apparently):

```ruby
class Foo
  STUFF = DATA.read # <class:Foo>: uninitialized constant Foo::DATA (NameError)
end

class Foo
  STUFF = ::DATA.read # <class:Foo>: uninitialized constant DATA (NameError)
end
```

Any idea how I could make this work?

Comment: See also: [HEREDOCS](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html).

Comment: @Ajedi32: yes, I considered a heredoc but my actual use case is storing a large-ish ERB template which would work best as trailing data.  With a heredoc I've got to fit it within the class definition scope but maybe that's the price to pay for not wanting to read from a separate file.

Comment: Can't confirm the error on `STUFF = DATA.read` : [snippet](http://ideone.com/6dbCoE).

Comment: @steenslag Very Good link.. I have never found.. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are already comments, that the error can't be confirmed, Babai also posted working examples.

Maybe you have another problem:

DATA corresponds to the text after `__END__` of the **main** document, not the actual source code file.

It works:

```
class Foo
  STUFF = DATA
  p STUFF.read
end
__END__
This is the stuff!
```

Here the source code file and the main file is the same.

But if you store it as `test_code.rb` and load it in a main file:

```
require_relative 'test_code.rb'
```

Then you get the error:

```
C:/Temp/test_code.rb:2:in `<class:Foo>': uninitialized constant Foo::DATA (NameError)
  from C:/Temp/test_code.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from test.rb:1:in `require_relative'
  from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

If your main file is again

```
require_relative 'test_code.rb'

__END__
This is the stuff!
```

Then the process works with the output *This is the stuff!*

To answer your question:

- You can't use `__END__` in a library, only as part of the main file.
- Use Here-documents instead - or store your data in an external data file.

Comment: "You can't use `__END__` in a library, only as part of the main file." <-- this explains it, I was using irb, not ruby.  Silly me... =)

Comment: @maerics You can use `__END__` in a library, it’s only `DATA` that’s not available. You just have to open the file yourself, e.g. using `__FILE__` or [`Kernel::caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) to get the filename. Have a look at what Sinatra does for it’s inline templates as an example: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1254-1283.

Comment: @matt You are half right ;) You may use `DATA` in a library, but it's the text after `__END__` of the main file, not the `__END__` of the library file. If the main file has no `__END__`, then `DATA` is not available.

Comment: @knut Any file can have `__END__`, and you can always get at that data, e.g. `File.read(__FILE__).split(/^__END__$\n/)[1]`. So while `DATA` will always refer to the text in the main file (if it’s there, so you can’t rely on it from a library), other files (including in a library) can have `__END__` sections and you can get at that data.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use `File.read(__FILE__).split("\n__END__\n", 2)[1]` instead of `DATA.read`

Answer (score 0):

Good blog is here:- [**`Useless Ruby Tricks: DATA and END`**](https://shifteleven.com/articles/2009/02/09/useless-ruby-tricks-data-and-__end__/)

This is how works:

```
class Foo
  def dis
    DATA.read
  end
end 
Foo.new.dis # => "This is the stuff!\n"
__END__
This is the stuff!
```

---

```
class Foo
  STUFF = DATA
  p STUFF.read
end
__END__
This is the stuff!
# >> "This is the stuff!\n"
```

---

```
RUBY_VERSION # => "2.0.0"
class Foo
  p STUFF = DATA.read 
end
__END__
This is the stuff!
# >> "This is the stuff!\n"
```

Comment: @maerics see now... :)