# Using __END__ and DATA in Chef recipes (to run legacy shell scripts)

Tags: chef-recipe

I'm migrating some shell scripts to Chef recipes. Some of these scripts are fairly involved, so just to make life easier in the short term and to avoid introducing bugs in rewriting everything in Chef/Ruby, I'd like to just run some of them as-is. They're all well-written and idempotent, so honestly there's no rush, but of course, the eventual goal is to rewrite them.

One cool feature of Ruby is its [`__END__`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__END__) keyword/method: *Lines below `__END__` will not be executed. Those lines will be available via the special filehandle DATA.*

It would be cool to ship the shell scripts as-is inside the the recipe after `__END__`, maybe something like the following, which I placed in `chef-repo/cookbooks/ruby-data-test/recipes/default.rb`:

```
file = Tempfile.new(File.basename(__FILE__))
file << DATA.read
bash file.path
file.unlink
__END__
echo "Hello, world"
```

However when I run this (with `chef-solo -c solo.rb --override-runlist 'recipe[ruby-data-test]'`), I get the following error:

```
[2014-10-03T17:14:56+00:00] ERROR: uninitialized constant Chef::Recipe::DATA
```

I'm pretty new to Chef, but I'm guessing the above is something about Chef wrapping my recipe in a class, and there's something simple preventing me from accessing `DATA`. Since it's "global" (?) I tried putting a dollar sign (`$DATA`) in front of it but that failed with:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `read' for nil:NilClass
```

So the question is: **How do I access `DATA` in my Chef recipe?** Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `::DATA.read`

Comment: Hmm, great idea. I tried `::DATA.read` but that unfortunately errored with `ERROR: uninitialized constant DATA`.

Comment: I'm thinking it may not be worth it, [the comments in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18520990/296829) indicate `DATA` is not accessible in a library, and points to [how Sinatra does it](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1254-1283): it reads in the file and splits on `__END__` manually. I could do that, or just ship the script separately, which might be better for syntax highlighting in my IDE anyway. Still curious if it can be done though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you don't have access to `DATA`, but you can fake it by reading in the current file yourself and splitting on `__END__`, [like Sinatra does](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1254-1283).

I ended up making a [Chef LWRP](https://docs.getchef.com/lwrp.html) for reuse. I don't know if I'll actually end up using this, but I wanted to figure it out. Like I said, I'm a Chef/Ruby noob, so any better ideas or suggestions welcome!

`ruby_data_test/recipes/default.rb`:

```
ruby_data_test_execute_ruby_data __FILE__

__END__
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
date
echo "Hello, world"
```

`ruby_data_test/resources/execute_ruby_data.rb`:

```
actions :execute_ruby_data
default_action :execute_ruby_data

attribute :source, :name_attribute => true, :required => true
attribute :args, :kind_of => Array
attribute :ignore_errors, :kind_of => [TrueClass, FalseClass], :default => false
```

`ruby_data_test/providers/execute_ruby_data.rb`:

```
def whyrun_supported?
    true
end

use_inline_resources

action :execute_ruby_data do
    converge_by("Executing #{@new_resource}") do
        Chef::Log.info("Executing #{@new_resource}")

        file_who_called_me = @new_resource.source

        io = ::IO.respond_to?(:binread) ? ::IO.binread(file_who_called_me) : ::IO.read(file_who_called_me)
        app, data = io.gsub("\r\n", "\n").split(/^__END__$/, 2)
        data.lstrip!

        file = Tempfile.new('execute_ruby_data')
        file << data
        file.chmod(0755)
        file.close

        exit_status =  ::Open3.popen2e(file.path, *@new_resource.args) do |stdin, stdout_and_stderr, wait_thr|
            stdout_and_stderr.each { |line| puts line }
            wait_thr.value # exit status
        end
        if exit_status != 0 && !@new_resource.ignore_errors
            throw RuntimeError
        end

    end
end
```

Here's the output:

```
$ chef-solo -c solo.rb --override-runlist 'recipe[ruby_data_test]'  
Starting Chef Client, version 11.12.4
[2014-10-03T21:50:29+00:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2014-10-03T21:50:29+00:00] WARN: Original Run List: []
[2014-10-03T21:50:29+00:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[ruby_data_test]]
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: ruby_data_test::default
  * ruby_data_test_execute_ruby_data[/root/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks/ruby_data_test/recipes/default.rb] action execute_ruby_dataFri Oct  3 21:50:29 UTC 2014
Hello, world

    - Executing ruby_data_test_execute_ruby_data[/root/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks/ruby_data_test/recipes/default.rb]


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete

Chef Client finished, 1/1 resources updated in 1.387608 seconds
```